# Migrating from Latin1 SQL Server to utf8mb4 MySQL Incorrect String Error Problems

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

**Final Update**

I was able to easily migrate the data with Talend. No errors, and it worked perfectly the first time with no special settings. This shows what an utter piece of garbage the MySQL Workbench Migration tool is. While the learning curve of Talend is rough (it's not intuitive at all), it appears to be one of the best data migration solutions out there. I recommend using it. Note I never figured out why the migration failed (as seen below). I'm just walking away from the utter garbage Oracle has pushed on the community. Oh, and Talend migrated the data to utf8mb4/utf8_general_ci without a hitch.

**Please note there are updates at the bottom.**

We have to migrate an export from TrackerRMS (which luckily doesn't have FK constraints, but the data is a total mess) to MySQL. Restoring the backup of the TrackerRMS data to SQL Server is cake; no issues. The problem is copying the data from SQL Server to MySQL.

MySQL Workbench Migration can handle all but 4 of the tables; but those 4 tables are the key problem. They have crazy content in their fields which causes the migration tool to choke. I attempted to export the data as .sql from HeidiSQL and it chokes as well.

The source table problem fields are `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation.

Note I've tried changing the collation of the source SQL Server table columns to `Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8` and `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8` and there is no effect.

The errors are:

```
ERROR: `Backup_EmpowerAssociates`.`BACKUP_documents`:Inserting Data: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x93\x8A x...' for column 'filepath' at row 13
ERROR: `Backup_EmpowerAssociates`.`BACKUP_activities`:Inserting Data: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x80' for column 'subject' at row 42
ERROR: `Backup_EmpowerAssociates`.`BACKUP_resourcehistory`:Inserting Data: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x91\x82(\xF0...' for column 'jobdescription' at row 80
```

This tells me the source data has 4-byte character details (which is beyond the standard utf8). Note the destination database in MySQL is utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci collated, and has the default settings as such. No connection settings override this.

When migrating I use Microsoft SQL Server and ODBC (native) for localhost (SQL Server) with default options. I've also tried turning ANSI off, but it has no impact. Note the ODBC configuration for SQL Server has no charset or collation settings or options. For target, I use the localhost stored connection which I use for general access.

Note the MySQL Workbench migration tool defines the receiving table columns (for the above problem columns) as LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'.

Could the issue be the migration proxy (ODBC?) is somehow converting it to utf8 (even though I don't have that selected)? But if that was the case, wouldn't the incoming data not be erroring out in the migration process as a UTF8MB4 solution (4-byte vs less)?

Note I tried creating and adjusting the destination MySQL table (by adjusting the SQL in the migration tool) as CHARSET latin1 and latin1_general_ci collation. Same issue.

Migration simply does not want to work (this is with SQL Server source being `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`). And I've tried it with UTF8 both on and off for driver. No effect.

Does anyone with migration experience recognize this issue, or have recommendations on how to resolve the problem? I'm fine with scrubbing the source data in SQL Server before I migrate - I just don't know the best method to do that (or if it's necessary).

Thanks!

===

**UPDATE 1**

This is very strange; using the below technique to show values that won't convert, this is the result:

```
SELECT filepath, CONVERT(varchar,filepath) FROM BACKUP_documents WHERE filepath <> CONVERT(varchar, Filepath);
```

[image: Results from the above]

Why on earth is the data being truncated upon convert with a simple filename at the "c" in documents?

Here's a capture that might also help resolve this issue.

[image: The characters that might be tripping things up]

But the strange part is MSSQL is showing normal text (without special characters) as being non-ASCII. I'm wondering if the folks at TrackerRMS are running code written in another country/language and it's messing up the data, but it's something that's not visible?

**UPDATE 2**

So to make things clear, here's what one of the characters that is messing up the data looks like.

[image: The 'graph' character]

Comment: FYI, UTF-8 is a variable length encoding that can run out to six bytes. The four bytes you're thinking of are the decoded 32-bit code points (4 bytes). Your problem isn't that "UTF-8 is too long" it's probably that U+9FF0 in your first two examples wasn't actually a valid character until [Unicode 13.0](https://unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/) was introduced in 2020. Here's the [WG2 Consent Docket](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2019/19250-wg2-consent-docket.pdf) for reference where they ask for the allocation. The tools you're using probably don't support Unicode 13.0.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning hmm I find it hard to believe TrackerRMS is so "modern". Regardless, is it possible to scrub the data on the MSSQL side (the truth is we don't need whatever crazy characters they have in there), or do I have to buy a tool to do this? I've wasted so much time trying to figure it out, I'm quite exhausted with the whole thing... that and I still don't understand what the real core problem is. This whole collation nightmare is just absurd. Wish I could simply transfer raw data and then define how to collate it after the fact...

Comment: Note I just added some test results to the OP. This is very strange.... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to easily migrate the data with Talend. No errors, and it worked perfectly the first time with no special settings. This shows what an utter piece of garbage the MySQL Workbench Migration tool is. While the learning curve of Talend is rough (it's not intuitive at all), it appears to be one of the best data migration solutions out there. I recommend using it. Note I never figured out why the migration failed (as seen below). I'm just walking away from the utter garbage Oracle has pushed on the community. Oh, and Talend migrated the data to utf8mb4/utf8_general_ci without a hitch.